# cross compile c++ on linux to windows

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compilation

```
clang++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -target x86_64-unknown-win32 -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/include/
main.cpp:6:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found
#include <string>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

that's weird because:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/include/ssp$ ls
ssp.h  stdio.h  string.h  unistd.h
```

and this result the same:

```
clang++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -target x86_64-unknown-win32 -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/include/ssp
```

well. I used to compile c code from linux to windows just fine using:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc main.c
```

and I tried:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp
```

also:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp  -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6/include
```

still give bunch of errors like

```
main.cpp:70:23: sorry, unimplemented: non-static data member initializers
main.cpp:70:23: error: in-class initialization of static data member ‘origin’ of non-literal type
main.cpp: In constructor ‘Item::Item(std::string)’:
main.cpp:83:18: error: ‘stoul’ is not a member of ‘std’
main.cpp:88:4: error: ‘origin’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:89:17: error: ‘stof’ is not a member of ‘std’
main.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Item&)’:
....
```

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 4.6.3`  seems to be the latest version on ubuntu repo.

I'm at lost..why the hell clang won't use the headers. why the hell x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ won't listen that it should use c++11 standards.

Comment: is string.h and string the same? I think not.

Comment: Mingw has notoriously lacking builds and are usually quite out of date when installed from the package manager. The errors you show are probably because they actually aren't supported in that build.

Comment: On second glance, you are using GCC 4.6.3. That definitely doesn't support the features you are after, you should look about updating MinGW to a 4.8 or 4.9 build (I don't know whether 4.9 is supported yet)

Comment: @CoffeeandCode please don't spread FUD. You don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: @C19 Ubuntu 14.04 provides [MinGW-w64 GCC 4.8.2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gcc-mingw-w64), which should support what you need. Time to update your system! Note that if you build clang yourself with [this patch](http://reviews.llvm.org/D3420) you should be able to use Clang with your MinGW-w64 headers/libraries. It will still use MinGW-w64 GCC's libstdc++, so make sure the version of the library you have installed has the features required.

Comment: @rubenvb It isn't FUD. I am talking from experience. Every time I've had to do a cross-compile I've tried to use MinGW (I want to use MinGW) but it's always been very outdated. The best experience I've had was with MinGW-builds on windows, that was very easy and up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

The GCC version you use does not support `non-static data member initializers` as shown [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/cxx0x_status.html). Find out [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) which version of GCC supports the C++11 feature set you required.